# iSCSI auto startup at boot 14.04

Tags: boot, server, 14.04, iscsi

I'm running Trusty Tahr (14.04) server. I've attached an iscsi disk and mounted it, mkfs, etc. works great, if I do it manually.

I'd much prefer to have my box mount the disk at boot so I've modified /etc/iscsi/iscsid.conf by removing the comment hash
node.startup = automatic and commenting out node.startup = manual (note: this isn't the default, but i've tried it both ways and i'm sticking with the automatic as that makes sense)

*node.startup = automatic
`#`

`#` node.startup = manual*

fstab looks good. i've git my block id set, _netdev is set, and as I stated earlier, manually, everything works. if I mount the disk, the fstab config leads the mount correctly.

in general use, things look good. (in fact, it's a time machine backup).

My only issue is, why isn't this working at boot? Boot.log shows this info:

** Starting iSCSI initiatior service iscsid                               [ OK ]

iscsiadm: No records found

* Setting up iSCSI targets                                                * Stop*

Clearly, an error is evident, but where? Aside from having to issue:
sudo iscsiadm -m node --login
I don't have to intervene.

Just .... need ... that ... last ... piece.
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you don't have any nodes configured in /etc/iscsi/nodes. In fact the nodes directory will be empty if you haven't asked for a list of targets from the iscsi server. So, if that's the case, you'll need to do a target discovery. Try: 
`iscsiadm -m discovery -t st -p IP-Address-Of-Target`

Once this is done, there will be an iqn... directory with a list of possible portals under the nodes dir:

```
/etc/iscsi/nodes/iqnname/192.168.0.1:servername.iscsiTargetName/default
```

Edit the file 'default' `so node.startup = automatic` on any target you want to automatically connect to.

Oh also, check /var/log/syslog to see if iscsi is starting before the network interfaces start.

Comment: as stated in my initial post, it worked except the reboot, hence the targets are listed in the nodes directory. the syslog shows the network being active before the iscsi daemon is initialized. HOWEVER, my mistake was in not realizing that I had to modify the targets default settings as well as the iscsid.conf file. Once I added your suggest of modifying the target's node default file, this now works at boot. Many thanks.